# Minimal polynomial is irreducible

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Suppose $\mathbb{E}$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{F}$.

If $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}$ we define the minimal polynomial for $a$ as the monic irreducible generator $g$ of the ideal $$I=\{f\in \mathbb{F}[x]|f(a)=0\} \subset \mathbb{F}[x]$$
But I don't understand: $g$ already has a root $a$,so how it can be irreducible?

Comment: Presumably $a$ is in $\mathbb{E}$ and (in all interesting cases) $a$ is not in $\mathbb{F}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $a \in \mathbb{E}\setminus \mathbb{F}$

You have to ask yourself a fondamental question: WHERE I'm valuating the polynomial $f$?

By your definition you are saying that $I$ is the ideal of the polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}$ such that have $a$ as rooth **as polynomials of $\mathbb{E}[x]$**.

Now $I$ is an ideal and you can take its generator that have to be irreducible by question of disivibility.

This generator is you minimal polynomial and is **irreducible as polynomial of $\mathbb{F}[x]$, not as polynomial in $\mathbb{E}[x]$**.

Observe that your ideal $I$ can be viewed in another way:

Consider the ideal $J \subset \mathbb{E}[x]$ of the polynomial $p$ such that $p(a)=0$.
Easily $J=(x-a)$.

Noy your ideal $I$ is exactely the ideal $J^c=J \cap \mathbb{F}[x]$.